# select rows based on date (one day before and after certain date) based on two data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frame as follows:

anom_df:

```
 date         id  country     anoms
 2017-01-01   26      US        0
 2017-01-02   26      US        0
 2017-01-03   26      US        9
 2017-01-04   26      US        0
 2017-01-05   26      US        0
 2017-01-06   26      US        0
 2017-01-07   26      US        0
 2017-01-08   26      US        0
 2017-01-09   26      US        100
 2017-01-10   26      US        0
```

and the master_df is

```
date         id     country    value     
 2017-01-01   26      US        2            
 2017-01-02   26      US        4             
 2017-01-03   26      US        9             
 2017-01-04   26      US        2             
 2017-01-05   26      US        4             
 2017-01-06   26      US        1
 2017-01-07   26      US        5
 2017-01-08   26      US        3
 2017-01-09   26      US        100
 2017-01-10   26      US        4
```

I want to create third table from master_df and join with anom_df to select only dates that has value in anom column in anom$table and one day before and one day after that date from master_df

Finally I want to have the following table

```
 date         id  country     value
 2017-01-02   26      US        2
 2017-01-03   26      US        9
 2017-01-04   26      US        4
 2017-01-08   26      US        3
 2017-01-09   26      US        100
 2017-01-10   26      US        4
```

I have tried the following code to find the shortlisted datafrmae:

```
before_after_anom<- dplyr::left_join(master_df,anom_df,by=c('id','country','date')) 
%>% mutate(diff = value - lag(value))
```

However it does not give me the proper dataframe, could you please help me how to filter it.

Comment: Can you explain your expected output? How do you get first 3 rows as output with `country = 'US'` and the corresponding `value` ?

Comment: sorry I have edited the dataframe. I want to select one day before and one day after and also the certain day which has value in anom_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't match your expected output but matches the description that you have.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(master_df, anom_df, by = c('country', 'id', 'date')) %>%
  slice({inds <- which(anoms != 0); c(inds - 1, inds, inds + 1)}) %>%
  arrange(date)

#        date id country value anoms
#1 2017-01-02 26      US     4     0
#2 2017-01-03 26      US     9     9
#3 2017-01-04 26      US     2     0
#4 2017-01-07 26      US     5     0
#5 2017-01-08 26      US     3   100
#6 2017-01-09 26      US   100     0
```

We find out non-zero indices in `anoms` and select rows one row above and below those indices.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

> I want to create the third table from master_df and join with
>   anom_df to select only dates that have value in anom column in
>   anom$table

It is a semi-join operation.

```r
master_df <- read_delim("data/master_df", delim = "\\s")
```

```r
(
    anom_df <-
        "date         id  country     anoms
2017-01-01   26      US        0
2017-01-02   26      US        0
2017-01-03   26      US        9
2017-01-04   26      US        0
2017-01-05   26      US        0
2017-01-06   26      US        0
2017-01-07   26      US        0
2017-01-08   26      US        100
2017-01-09   26      US        0
2017-01-09   26      US        0" %>%
    str_replace_all("[:blank:]+", ",") %>%
    read_csv()
)
```

```
## # A tibble: 10 x 4
##    date          id country anoms
##    <date>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
##  1 2017-01-01    26 US          0
##  2 2017-01-02    26 US          0
##  3 2017-01-03    26 US          9
##  4 2017-01-04    26 US          0
##  5 2017-01-05    26 US          0
##  6 2017-01-06    26 US          0
##  7 2017-01-07    26 US          0
##  8 2017-01-08    26 US        100
##  9 2017-01-09    26 US          0
## 10 2017-01-09    26 US          0
```

```r
(
    master_df <-
        "date         id     country    value
2017-01-01   26      AF        2
2017-01-02   26      US        4
2017-01-03   26      US        9
2017-01-04   26      AF        2
2017-01-05   26      US        4
2017-01-06   26      BE        1
2017-01-07   26      US        5
2017-01-08   26      US        3
2017-01-09   26      US        100
2017-01-10   26      US        4 " %>%
    str_replace_all("[:blank:]+", ",") %>%
    read_csv()
)
```

```
## Warning: 1 parsing failure.
## row col  expected    actual         file
##  10  -- 4 columns 5 columns literal data

## # A tibble: 10 x 4
##    date          id country value
##    <date>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
##  1 2017-01-01    26 AF          2
##  2 2017-01-02    26 US          4
##  3 2017-01-03    26 US          9
##  4 2017-01-04    26 AF          2
##  5 2017-01-05    26 US          4
##  6 2017-01-06    26 BE          1
##  7 2017-01-07    26 US          5
##  8 2017-01-08    26 US          3
##  9 2017-01-09    26 US        100
## 10 2017-01-10    26 US          4
```

```r
master_df %>% 
    semi_join(anom_df,by=c('id','country','date'))
```

```
## # A tibble: 6 x 4
##   date          id country value
##   <date>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
## 1 2017-01-02    26 US          4
## 2 2017-01-03    26 US          9
## 3 2017-01-05    26 US          4
## 4 2017-01-07    26 US          5
## 5 2017-01-08    26 US          3
## 6 2017-01-09    26 US        100
```

> one day before and one day after that date from master_df

But I don’t know what’s meaning of that? Just get a difference?

Comment: I do not understand how do you semi_join to find one before and one day after of rows which has value in anom data, i also revised the master_table could you please check it